# Javascript regular expression : match 2 substrings in any order

Tags: javascript, regex

After reading how to write a regexp in Javascript, I'm still pretty confused how to write this one...

I want to match every string containing at least one occurence of 2 substrings, in any order.

Say sub1 = "foo" and sub2 = "bar"

foo => doesn't match

bar => doesn't match

foobar => matches

barfoo => matches

foohellobar => matches

Could somebody help me with this ?

Additionnally, I'd like to exclude another substring. So it would match the strings containing the 2 substrings like before, but not containing a sub3, regardless of its order with the 2 others.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
str.indexOf(sub1) > -1 && str.indexOf(sub2) > -1
```

Or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) in ES6:

```js
str.includes(sub1) && str.includes(sub2)
```

Or if you have an array of substrings:

```js
[sub1, sub2/*, ...*/].every(sub => str.includes(sub));
```

Comment: but.. wouldn't one match be faster than several indexOf ?

Comment: @mens But a substring check is probably faster than a regex match. Regexes have more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
/.*foo.*bar|.*bar.*foo/g
```

`.*` matches 0 or many characters (where `.` matches any character and `*` stands for 0 or many)

`|` is regex' or operator

Generated code from regex101:

var re = /.*foo.*bar|.*bar.*foo/g;
var str = 'foobar';
var m;

```
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hW5qI2/1)

That being said, better use Oriol's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32937862/3993662) using `indexOf()` or `includes()`.

Comment: why is it better to use indexOf ? I thought a single match would be faster

Comment: I think the performance difference isn't notable, but the indexOf is more, includes() way more, readable. @mens

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a complicated regex, but instead just used logical operand `&&`.

```js
var param = 'foobar'; 
alert(param.match(/foo/) && param.match(/bar/) && !param.match(/zoo/));

param = 'foobarzoo'; 
alert(param.match(/foo/) && param.match(/bar/) && !param.match(/zoo/));
```